# Supertest custom express server in node

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, mocha.js

Please be gentle with me. I'm new to async coding and have been thrown headfirst into an intensive project using node to develop and API server. I'm loving it but some things aren't coming naturally.

Our project is built using express js. We have a file, server.js where we instantiate an express server which in turn instantiates our router and so on. I need to integration test this now (partially) complete server. Normally what I do is from the command line run '%node server.js' and then using either python requests or curl make requests and check the responses.

Now I've been tasked with writing a unit and integration test suite so that we can automate our testing going forward. I've been using mocha and now am trying to use supertest for the integration testing. The problem is that supertest expects a server object which it then applies tests to however our file that builds our server object doesn't return anything. I don't want to modify that file so I am stumped as to how to access the server object to use for testing.

My server file looks (in part) like this:

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

// Express Configuration
app.use(express.favicon()); //handles favicon request, which keeps it out of the log when using a browser :)
app.use(express.bodyParser()); //slurps up the body in chunks the node.js way :)
// ...and so on
```

and my mocha test file looks like this

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , app     = require('../server.js')
  , assert  = require("assert");

describe('POST /', function(){
  it('should fail bad img_uri', function(done){
    request(app)
        .post('/')
        .send({
            'img_uri' : 'foobar'
        })  
        .expect(500)
        .end(function(err, res){
        console.dir(err)
        console.dir(res)
            done();
        })  
  })    
})
```

when I run this test I get a complaint about the app object not having a method named address. My question is, is there a way I can require/call the server.js file so that the app object will be in scope? Or am I going about this wrong. I also played around a little bit with using http.js to make calls directly to the server but didn't have luck that way either. Thanks!

Comment: The error I get when running this is:
"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'address'"

and the stacktrace refers to the line in my test file:
"request(app)"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to export the `app` object in `server.js`:

```
var app = express();

module.exports = app;

...
```

Comment: Express is exporting app by default, but supertest still complains that it cant find the address method. There might be an issue in later versions of express?